# How to use the built-in unit testing module?

Tags: phpunit, kohana-3

There seems to be a built-in [unit test module](https://github.com/kohana/unittest) in Kohana 3.x.

How can I use this? I can't find any official documentation regarding this module and even Google doesn't provide good articles.

I would appreciate good links or any kind `Hello, World!` unit test example!

Answer (score 0):

Enable the module in your bootstrap.php by uncommenting it and go to /unittest/ in your browser. There are several example tests included.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But first of all: I found out, that I first had to download PHPUnit Test to use the build in module. Second: I still get an error: Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php'. So it actually seems to be a bit harder, than just uncommenting the module in bootstrap.php